# Finding the two highest scores using file input

Tags: java

Since we haven't covered arrays and lists yet, he said to stick to loops and if statements.
I can't seem to figure out how to make it display the names of the two highest scores from the text file. Also I can't figure out how to make it display two scores that are identical. Here is what I've done so far:

```
package lab06;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Lab06 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner lab06txt = new Scanner(new File("Lab06.txt"));
    Scanner duplicateScanner = new Scanner(new File("Lab06.txt"));
    int totalstudents = 0;
    int grade = 0;
    int grade2 = 0;
    int record = 0;       
    int Highest = 0;
    int Highest2 = 0;
    int ACounter = 0;
    int BCounter = 0;
    int CCounter = 0;
    int DCounter = 0;
    int FCounter = 0;
    double average = 0;
    String lastName = "";
    String lastNameHigh = "";
    String lastNameHigh2 = "";
    String firstName = "";
    String firstNameHigh = "";
    String firstNameHigh2 = "";
    while (lab06txt.hasNext()){
        record ++;
        totalstudents++;
        lastName = lab06txt.next();
        firstName = lab06txt.next();
        grade = lab06txt.nextInt();
        {
            average += grade;
            if (grade >= Highest){
                Highest = grade;
                firstNameHigh = firstName;
                lastNameHigh = lastName;
            }                        

        }

        {
        if ((grade >= 90) && (grade <= 100))
        {
           ACounter++;         
        }
        if ((grade >= 80) && (grade <= 89))
        {
           BCounter++;         
        }
        if ((grade >= 70) && (grade <= 79))
        {
           CCounter++;         
        }
        if ((grade >= 60) && (grade <= 69))
        {
           DCounter++;         
        }
        if ((grade < 60))
        {
           FCounter++;         
        }
        if ((grade < 0) || (grade > 100))
        {
            System.out.print("Score is out of bounds in record " + record + ": " + lastName + " "+ firstName + " " + grade + ".\nProgram ending\n");
            return;

        }
       }
    }
    while(lab06txt.hasNext())
    {
        lastName = lab06txt.next();
        firstName = lab06txt.next();
        grade2 = lab06txt.nextInt();           
        if(grade2 > Highest2 && grade2 < Highest){
            Highest2 = grade2;
                firstNameHigh2 = firstName;
                lastNameHigh2 = lastName;
        }
    }


    System.out.println("Total students in class:        " +totalstudents);
    System.out.println("Class average:                  " + average/totalstudents);
    System.out.println("Grade Counters: ");
    System.out.println("A's     B's     C's     D's     F's");
    System.out.printf(ACounter + "%7d %7d %8d %7d\n", BCounter,CCounter,DCounter,FCounter);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Top Two Students: \n");

    System.out.printf(lastNameHigh + " " + firstNameHigh + "%15d \n", Highest);
    System.out.printf(lastNameHigh2 + " " + firstNameHigh2 + "%15d\n", Highest2);


}
```

}

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: You mixed up the assignment of your variables. Have a look at this line for example `firstName = firstNameHigh;` Should be the other way around if I interpret your code correctly.

Comment: Thank You! Can't believe it was so simple ahahaha.

Answer (score 1):

The two parts of your code where you have:

```
firstName = firstNameHigh;
lastName = lastNameHigh;
```

should be:

```
firstNameHigh  = firstName;
lastNameHigh = lastName;
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem with displaying the names. But now I've come across another problem. For the scores, the second highest score is displaying as 97 when the second highest score is actually 98. Also how would I get it to display the duplicate scores.

Comment: Finding duplicates without using an array gets a bit tedious, but what you could do is have a method or a block of code which creates a new scanner Scanner duplicateScanner = new Scanner(new File("Lab06.txt")); and have that see if the current number comes up 2 or more times making it a duplicate

Comment: Yeah I'm stuck. In the sample run provided by my professor it displays:    Top two students:

        Glaude Jeanette       99
        Florez Katarzyna  98. But I'm getting 
Glaude Jeanette             99 
Klein Harry             97 For some reason my code won't assign the correct second highest score. Also I will give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: It seems that when your finding the second highest grade, you haven't necessarily found the highest grade yet making if (grade > Highest2 && grade < Highest) not run as expected. what you could do is first just look for the highest grade
and then have another while loop at the end of the method which looks for the second highest grade

Comment: so bassicaly when you get to the second highest score, since you've already assigned it to the highest score, your if statment, just skips the value

Comment: I made a new while loop after the first while loop and I created a variable called grade2. However it comes back as 0 instead of giving me a grade. I updated the original post to what I've added so far.

Comment: thats probably because your using your old scanner lab06.txt rather then duplicateScanner, or you could just reinstantiate your old scanner before the while loop

also Highest2 = grade; should be Highest2 = grade2;

Comment: What do you mean by reinstatiate my old scanner? Also using the duplicateScanner fixed it and now it displays the correct second highest score.